# Can't get PL SQL to divide with two select statements

Tags: plsql

I need help getting this code to work.  I am trying to use two sql statements to perform a division.

```
 select ((select count(p.issued) 
 from permit p
 where trunc(p.issued) >= trunc(TO_DATE('1/1/2011','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
 AND trunc(p.issued) <= trunc(TO_DATE('1/31/2011','MM/DD/YYYY')))
 /
 (select count(p.issued)  
 from permit p
where (TO_DATE(p.issued) - sysdate) <= 21
and trunc(p.issued) >= trunc(TO_DATE('1/1/2011','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
AND trunc(p.issued) <= trunc(TO_DATE('1/31/2011','MM/DD/YYYY')))) as permitPercemt;
```

Comment: -1 You have edited your original question's code example to reflect the correct answer. Please don't do that, it's very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add one more `SELECT` :

```
SELECT ( (select ....)/(select ... )) as permitPercent FROM DUAL;
```

**UPDATE**
So your query will look like:

```
SELECT (
(
  select count(p.issued)  
  from permit p 
  where trunc(p.issued) >= trunc(TO_DATE('1/1/2011','MM/DD/YYYY'))  
  AND trunc(p.issued) <= trunc(TO_DATE('1/31/2011','MM/DD/YYYY'))
) /
(
  select count(p.issued)      
  from permit p    
  where (TO_DATE(p.issued) - sysdate) <= 21    
  and trunc(p.issued) >= trunc(TO_DATE('1/1/2011','MM/DD/YYYY'))     
  AND trunc(p.issued) <= trunc(TO_DATE('1/31/2011','MM/DD/YYYY'))
)
) as permitPercent FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Which is less than three selects, as recommended by a1ex07.

Comment: @recursive, I have two things to say to that comment. 1) :-); 2) It's not a recommendation; it's a necessary fact..!

Comment: tried three selects and got this error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 35 Column: 70

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator Can you update your original post with your code that uses the 3 selects?

Comment: Guys thanks for all the help in this matter!  I have just added the updated post.

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator, you seem to be missing a `from`... add `from dual` at the end; and your `as` at the end is nested incorrectly ( and unnecessary)

Comment: @BronoTheVibrator : Check updated answer, it should work for you

Answer (score 1):

you don't divide the entire select statement.

you divide two values and return that as a column in the select list.

Comment: could you kindly provide an example of how I could do that with this code?